# Mysterious black bar appears under UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am experiencing a problem while adding subviews to a viewController. 
I am trying to make a floating button on top of a UITableView like the facebook messenger app's 'create new chat' button.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:viewController.view.frame];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(240, 340, 50, 50);
[viewController.view addSubview:tableView];
[viewController.view addSubview:imageView];
```

This works as desired, leaving the image floating at my desired position and the tableView scrollable but it introduces a small black bar under the UINavigationBar and i don't understand why its appearing.

[image]

Comment: Try with `UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:viewController.view.bounds];`

Comment: also check your auto layout/springs & struts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `viewController.view.frame` to `viewController.view.bounds`

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:viewController.view.bounds];
```

If you look at frame params, you'll see, that `viewController.view.frame.origin.y > 0.0f`.

> frame – This rectangle defines the size and position of the view in
> its superview’s coordinate system
>
> bounds – The bounds rectangle, which
> describes the view’s location and size in its own coordinate system.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Comment: Wow, this actually fixed it. It is now on my list of little quirks that can happen and to look out for. Thanks a lot for the quick answer.

Comment: @0xec74, Isn't this same what I have mentioned in my comment on question and answer? Apart from copy pasting frame and bounds from documentation is there anything else added to it?

Comment: @ACB, On the moment of writing my answer, your answer was http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14508905/1

Comment: @0xEC74, Yes, first I have added as a comment and then posted as an answer but while copying, I mistyped the frame there and I corrected it later. You can see that my comment is still the correct one which was there in your answer as well later. Cant see anything different  added in your answer.

Comment: @ACB, Yes, your comment is correct. But does not answer the question, why? This is the difference. And you did not have an _answer_ that I could adjust whithout rewriting. If you still do not see the difference, I can not help you.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cant agree to your statement. I wanted to point out the plagiarism since I have seen the same in some other questions as well.

Comment: 0xEC74 check the @ACB's comment - is with 1 hour before your response

Comment: @TonyMkenu, Thanks. Anyways I have removed my answer. There is no point in keeping both answer with same content.